# Do I have to convert my project file to use MSBuild 4?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I have a C# `.proj` file that using .Net Framework 3.5. Currently the solution that ties the `.proj` files uses Visual Studio 2008. Our daily build currently uses MSBuild 3.5. I know that you can specify the `TargetFramework` in MSBbuild 4.

My question is: do I have to convert my project file using Visual Studio 2010? I am assuming the conversion only affects the `.sln` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion using Visual Studio 2010 is the easiest way, but you can just update your project files manually: just add `ToolsVersion="4.0"` attribute on the `Project` node. So yes, you have to convert your `.proj` files too, changing only the `.sln` is not enough.

Comment: +1 for the response. The reason why I didn't want to convert yet because our shop still need to use visual studio 2008. However I need to use some feature in MSBUILD 4 which is the XML Document Transformation(XDT) feature. So far I have used MSBUILD 4 on some of the non converted .proj files successfully. My concern is there might be different output and also it might break on some non converted .proj files when building it.